# const pointer and pointer to const value as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have a program like below and expect that:

1. with function `void myFunc1 ( const int *x)` ==> I cannot change the value of at the memory location that `x` points to, but can change the memory location that `x` points to.
2. with function `void myFunc2 ( int const *x)` ==> I cannot change the location that `x` points to as it is a const pointer. But I could change the value at the memory location that `x` points to.

However, upon compiling the code, I don't see the difference between `const int *x` vs `int const *x`:

1. in both function, the lines `*x=8` in both function return error. I didn't expect error from `myFunc2` because it is a `const` pointer, not a pointer to a `const` value.
2. in `myFunc1`, I expected to see value 5 after `myFunc1` is close.

Could the experts here explain my 2 unexpected results above ? Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int a = 5;                      // declared a global,

void myFunc1 ( const int *x) {  // const parameter: pointer to a const int value.
    // *x= 8;                   // error: assignment of read-only location ‘* x’ ==> cannot change the value at the location pointed by pointer. This is expected
    printf("%d \n ", *x);       
    x = &a;                     // can change where the pointer point to. 
                                // a is global and is not loss after closing myFunc2
    printf("value in myFunc1: %d \n ", *x);                           
}


void myFunc2 ( int const *x) {   // const parameter: const pointer, cannot change the address that x points to. 
    //  *x= 8;                  // error: assignment of read-only location ‘* x’ 
    printf("%d \n ", *x);       
    x = &a;                     // no compiling error here. This is not expected.
                                
    printf("value in myFunc2: %d \n ", *x);                           
}

int main() {
    int *y;
    int z = 6;
    y = &z;
    printf("value before myFunc1: %d \n", *y);     
    myFunc1(y);
    printf("value after  myFunc1: %d \n", *y);        // expect to print 5. Result: print 6.
    
    printf("value before myFunc2: %d \n", *y);     
    myFunc2(y);
    printf("value after  myFunc2: %d \n", *y);        // expect to print 8 if the line *x=8 could be compiled . Result: print 6.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your understanding of 2 isn't quite correct. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const) for more. Both `const int*` and `int const*` are non-constant pointers to constant `int`s. A constant pointer to a non-constant `int` would be `int * const`.

Comment: Reading declarations from right to left gets you `const int *x` = "x is a pointer to an `int` that is constant" and `int const *x`= "x is a pointer to a constant `int`". Same, same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see the different between having 2 parameters (const int *x) vs (int const *x):

That's because `int const*` and `const int*` are the same thing.

If you want to make the *pointer* `const`, you have to put a `const` on its right, like this: `int * const`, a constant pointer to (non-constant) `int`eger.

---

### Unrelated (is it?) note on *East `const`*

I am one of those in favour of the so called *East `const`*, which means I prefer writing the `const` always on the right of what it applies to. For instance,

- for a "pointer to constant `int`", I write `int const *`,
- for a "constant pointer to constant `int`", I write `int const * const`.

As you see, the sentences in quotes map to the types if you read them right-to-left:

```cpp
//  1    2   3   4             4       3           2     1
   int const * const    // constant pointer to constant int
```

Furthermore, always thinking of `const` as something that can be put on the *right* of what it applies to has also other advantages, sometimes in terms of peculiarities of the language that you can discover.

For instance, the following is how I discovered something more about references.

Take the declaration of a function parameter taken by reference to constant: `int const& p`. If you write it like this and think of it the *East `const`* way, it is clear that it declaring a `p` which is a reference to a constant `int`, not a constant reference to `int`.

After all, thinking *East `const`*, what would a constant reference to `int` look like? It'd be `int & const`, with the `const` on the right of what we'd like it to apply to, the reference `&`. However, this syntax is incorrect.

Why is that? Why can't I make a reference constant? Because it always is, as references cannot rebind. The standard simply doesn't let you write something totally redundant as a `const` applied to a reference.

Comment: Agree. A little change over the position of * really makes a difference.
const * int                         = constant pointer to a value. 
int const *   = const int *  = both non-constant pointer to const value

Comment: `const * int` is invalid syntax.

Comment: int * const should be correct to show const pointer. Thanks for correcting me. 

But I still have another point in the question. 

In myFunc1 (const int *x). I expect to print value 5 after closing myFunc1 because I have change where x is pointed to. And it points to a global variable. Would you explain, why 5 is not printed out ?

Comment: @MinhPham In `myFunc1` `x` is a non-`const` pointer but it's still an argument being passed by value. Therefore it's a copy of the pointer `y` from main, not a reference, so changes to `x` have no effect on `y`.